# Best way to measure how much disk space a user of a web app is using?

Tags: web-applications, disk

I was wondering, what methods do people use for measuring how much disk space people are using in their account for a web app? For instance, if I want to cap a web app at 5GB of storage, what would you do to track that usage?

Thanks!

Comment: What language are you using?  What OS are you using?  This is a very open ended question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through all the user's uploaded files, sum up their file size and check if he is within quota, before you permit the user to upload a new file.

Or you could store how much capacity he has used up by adding/subtracting the file size when the user uploads/deletes a file from his account, and store this piece of data in the database.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was thinking of the latter and I was wondering if there were any alternatives that were perhaps better.